# JasperReports Server report permissions/roles

Tags: roles, jasperserver

We have a collection of reports on our *JasperReports Server* right now, most of which have input controls.

I recently implemented Roles, adding a specific role for the users of these reports (with the intention of adding additional roles in the future for other reports, not associated with this specific group).

All of the reports, some with, some without input controls are working with the exception of one that has a single input control (multi select query tied to a dropdown) that does not work for the users assigned to the role I just put in.  I can access it normally as *admin* user.

I have checked to make sure that the role has Execute only for the Queries and for that specific query, and for the actual Input Control and the report.

If I can post something that will help troubleshoot this issue, I'm happy to do so...looking for any ideas that might help...

Answer (score 1):

At this point we have not found a solution, however, I did delete the report from the server, and re-upload it from iReport, and reconnected the Input Control.  After that little exercise, everything is back to working normally, and the user with the assigned role has access to everything she needs.